# How to access a variable in a method of a different class in c++

Tags: c++

How to access a variable in a method in a different class for example in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Student
{
public:
    void Addition()
    {
        int c=17;
    }
};
int main()
{
    
}
```

How can i access variable **c** in **Addition** method in class **Student** without returning the value.

Thanks For Reading.

Have A Nice Day (:

Comment: This question seems out of C++ concept! Why do you need access to a variable declared and scoped in a CLASS method from another CLASS? ... This's very out of good C++ programming style.

Comment: Can you present some (pseudo)code of what you want to do? It's not very clear where do you want to access that variable.

Comment: What is the *actual* and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you think it would be solved by breaking the scoping rules of C++?

Comment: No sir just for self knowledge increment (:

Comment: Just programm a getter.

Comment: @Agent_A, for sure there's  no C++ legal code that might manage such a terrible idea!

Comment: By the way, the variable `int c`, as it is declared, is allocated on the stack dynamically when the method is invoked.

Comment: @MarcelSonderegger, `int c` is declared into the method and allocated on the stack, then is not possible to create a getter method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a setter and getter in your class, then use them to achieve what you want in the main

```
private:
  int c;
public:
  void setIntC(int intC) { c = intC; } 
  int getIntC() const { return c; }
```

Comment: the gettter should be `const`

Comment: In the question the `c` variable is not a member variable, it's local to the `Addition` method.

Comment: I don't think its possible to access ```int c``` in the function ```Addition()``` from the main. Unless some arguments are given to the function and the value is returned through a getter